# Mostrar los datos de una consulta de eloquent relacionadas con otras tablas anidadas en el .blade

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Estoy creando un sistema para abrir aulas para alumnos. Tengo 2 tablas principales para la creación y relación de las aulas, la primera es la tabla donde el alumno tendrá relacionado el aula del profesor, y la tabla *aula* contendrá la información del profesor.

En la tabla *contenedores* tiene el id del user y dentro de la tabla *user* contiene la llave foránea de la información de la cuenta el *id_cuenta*.

Hasta el momento he realizado las relaciones en los modelos y funciona bien en laravel tinker e igualmente he estado usando las consultas (querys) con muchos joins, pero al tener muchas relaciones las tablas, se vuelve una consulta demasiado grande y creo que con eloquent podría ahorrar líneas de código, por eso me he puesto a investigar y obtuve resultados pero me he trabado en esta parte.

He investigado en la documentación y he usado la siguiente consulta que sí me funciona:

```php
$prueba2 = aula_proceso_asignatura::with(['asesor_academico_pureba.cargo_academico'])
    ->findOrFail(3);
```

y me trae las relaciones; borré los datos por si acaso :)

```
  #original: array:9 [▼
    "id" => 3
    "id_coordinador_carrera" => 4
    "id_asesor_academico" => 85
    "id_proceso" => 1
    "id_carrera" => 3
    "id_periodo_escolars" => 3
    "id_estado_abierto_cerrado" => 1
    "created_at" => "//"
    "updated_at" => null
  ]
 
  #relations: array:1 [▼
   
      #attributes: array:10 [▼
        "id" => 85
        "ape_paterno_aa" => "...."
        "ape_materno_aa" => "///"
        "nombres_aa" => "////"
        "tel_lada_aa" => "///"
        "tel_num_aa" => "///"
        "email_aa" => "/////"
        "id_cargo_aa" => 8
        "id_user" => 5
        "id_carrera" => 4
      ]
      #observables: []
      #relations: array:1 [▼
        "cargo_academico" => App\Models\cargo {#1474 ▼
          #table: "cargo"
          #primaryKey: "id_cargo"
          #connection: "mysql"
          #keyType: "int"
          +incrementing: true
          #with: []
          #withCount: []
          +preventsLazyLoading: false
          #perPage: 15
          +exists: true
          +wasRecentlyCreated: false
          #escapeWhenCastingToString: false
          #attributes: array:2 [▼
            "id_cargo" => 8
            "nombre_cargo" => "Profesor"
          ]
```

Aquí bien: ya logré obtener la información de la tabla, pero quisiera saber cómo mostrar en la vista blade esa información, o separar la información de las tablas que tienen relaciones. Lo intenté de la siguiente manera:

```php
    $cargoAcade = $prueba2->asesor_academico_pureba()->cargo()->get();
    dd($cargoAcade);
```

pero obtengo el siguiente error:

> BadMethodCallException
> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo::cargo()

Anexo las relaciones de los modelos, están son alguna pruebas para obtener el cargo del asesor académico para entender como realizarlo con todas las siguientes relaciones, por que creo ya entender como hacer las consultas pero no como obtener los datos, solo quisiera saber como obtener los datos de las relaciones de asesor académico que en este caso seria cargo_academico.

modelo aula academica

class aula_proceso_asignatura extends Model
{
use HasFactory;

```
//relacion uno a muchos con la tabla proceso asignatura
public function procesos_asignaturas_alumno(){
    return $this->hasOne('App\Models\proceso_asignatura_alumno', 'id_aula_proceso_asignaturas');
}

//relacion 1 a 1 con la tabla  proceso
public function proceso(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\proceso', 'id_proceso');
}

//relacion 1 a 1 con la tabla coordinador carrera
public function coordinador_carrera(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\coordinadores_carreras', 'id_coordinador_carrera');
}
    //relacion 1 a 1 con la tabla  carrera
public function carrera(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\carrera', 'id_carrera');
}

 //relacion 1 a 1 con la tabla prueba asesor academico
public function asesor_academico_pureba(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\asesor_academico', 'id_asesor_academico');
}
```

}

modelo asesor academico

class asesor_academico extends Model
{

```
//relacion 1 a 1 con la tabla mensaje asesor academico
public function aula_proceso_asignatura(){
    return $this->hasOne('App\Models\aula_proceso_asignatura', 'id_asesor_academico'); 
}

//relacion 1 a 1 con la tabla  user
public function User(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\models\proceso', 'id');
}
//relacion 1 a 1 con la tabla  cargo
public function cargo_academico(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\models\cargo', 'id_cargo_aa');
}
```

}

modelo cargo

```
class cargo extends Model
{
    

    public function asesor_academico(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\asesor_academico', 'id_cargo_aa');
   }


}
```

Comment: Deberias incluir  el codigo de las relaciones de tus modelos.

Comment: vale, gracias por responder david, los voy a poner, la verdad no pensé incluirlo por que en si ya obtengo la consulta solo quería saber como aplicarlo a la vista, o en si acceder a las datos de las relaciones obtenidas de la tablas, pero podría ser que la relaciones en los modelos se deba realizar de diferente manera.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontré un error cuando intentas obtener el `cargo` a través de `asesor_academico_pureba`

```
$cargoAcade = $prueba2->asesor_academico_pureba()->cargo()->get();
```

Lo primero es que estás llamando `asesor_academico_pureba()` como función, en este caso la de la relación, como esta función no regresa una `Collection` no funcionará. Cuida también los errores al escribir (dice `pureba` en vez de `prueba`).

Como deberías de hacerlo es:

```
$cargoAcade = $prueba2->asesor_academico_pureba->cargo;
```

Así sí estás accediendo al registro `asesor_academico_pureba` asociado de `$prueba2`, a su vez, acceder al `cargo` de `asesor_academico_pureba` de la misma manera, y sin usar `get()` ya no es necesario.

Ahora bien, puedes usar los métodos de las relaciones para filtrar la información, por ejemplo, un `Cargo` puede ser el mismo para varios asesores académicos, entonces quieres filtrar a los acádemicos por su género, digamos que quieres todas los académicos mujeres desde el modelo `Cargo`:

```
Cargo::asesor_academico()->where('gender', 'Femenino')->get();
```

Y ese sería un uso para las relaciones, de otra forma, si no necesitas hacer filtrado, lo usarías como el primer ejemplo.

Eso es lo primero que hay que hacer, pero noto más cosas en tu código que podrías mejorar bastante:

Por convención las clases deberían empezar con mayúsculas:

```
class Cargo extends Model
```

Y en el caso de clases que formadas por más de una palabras deberías usar la convención `PascalCase` de esta manera

```
class AulaProcesoAsignatura extends Model
```

Y sigue esa misma convención para el nombrado de los archivos: `AulaProcesoAsignatura.php`

Ahora, el nombrado de las funciones, en este caso, las que defines para las relaciones entre modelos, la convención sería `camelCase`, cuidando el lenguaje natural para que si retorna varios registros sea nombrada en en plural y solo con leer se pueda entender qué debería de regresar:

```
public function asesoresAcademicos()
```

De la misma manera, si solo regresa un registro:

```
public function cargoAcademico()
```

Puedes consultar más estándares para PHP [aquí](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-1-basic-coding-standard.md)